# Survey database design - conditional questions based on answers from other questions

Tags: database-design, survey, conditional-statements

I'm trying to think of a good way to set up a sort of survey. One requirement is that questions pop up based on other questions' values, so for example if a user answers questionA with value "YES", then further down the road they will be asked `questionX`. This answer then needs to be mandatory (while `questionA` itself might have not been mandatory, though).

Right now I'm trying to decide whether to implement these conditions on the database layer or do it the way limesurvey does it: add simple expressions to questions which are evaluated at runtime, so for `questionX` that field would be `questionA.value == "YES"`, but it could become as complicated as `questionA.value == "YES" || (questionZ.value == "NO && questionF.value > 30)`.

Besides the obvious complications that arise of manually parsing these expressions at runtime, are there any other issues I might be forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you ask 10 people you'll get 10 different answers, but I would put the survey logic in an application layer and not in the database.

From personal experience, performance is most likely not going to be your biggest challenge. Maintaining the code around business rules is going to be the hardest thing.

My recommendation would be to put the rules/logic in the application layer so you can maintain your application well. Putting that kind of logic in the database gets very complex very fast.

Evaluating if statements and boolean expressions at runtime won't have an impact on performance. Just make sure you're not looping over sets of data excessively and I'm sure you'll be fine.